# I want to edit a test case in ALM while QTP script is running simultaneously on the same machine? How can we do that?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp, alm

I want to edit test case which is present in ALM while QTP script is running on the same machine at the same time. Can anybody please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Have you checked in the help guide the check-in / check-out solution? Then you can lock a test case and write the same as in git or svn.

Comment: @Marcosmdm No, I've not checked. Thanks for suggestion. Can you please explain more about "lock a test case and write the same" that will be great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below the checkout description coming from REST API library.

A different solution can be to implement a single point of report. It means you can create your own tool that is reporting real time to QC and it is also able to get real time input by QTP tool. (of course it is then more complicated)

Hope this can help you a bit! Have a nice day.

check-out description:
Checks out an entity.

URL
/qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/{entity collection}/{Entity ID}/versions/check-out

Remarks
POST the comment and version number with an XML compliant with the check-out-parameters Schema.

The version is optional. If not specified, the latest version is checked out.

The comment is optional. A comment can be entered either on check-in or check-out. If a comment is entered on check-in, it overrides any comment entered on check-out.

If neither a comment nor a version is specified, the input XML is not required. If no XML is sent, do not specify a content-type header.